# Flutter HTTP login with session and get data

Tags: api, flutter, http

[login secreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IICJN.png)

-

[categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVrJH.png)

[sub categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNsrE.png)

[topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akr1g.png)

I want to sort all the categories after user login as seen in the pictures. When I click on any of these categories, sub-categories need to be opened. And when clicking on any of these sub-categories, I want the subject and the content of the subject to be opened.PM and info information must be taken.so all must be with the session.

How can I do these steps? What steps do I need to take?

Comment: Can you add the pictures you are mentioning to your question?

Comment: i added the pictures, sir.

Comment: @R.Shpd  i added.